# Refresh the browser cache for same call to an event updated file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, caching, browser

Here is my scenario

1. Asp. net website
2. Angular app embedded via IFrame
3. First user clicks on the .net button that saves a response in a .csv file on the server. On every click different data is updated on the file
4. Then user clicks on the angular page, which gets the data from that file using a link.

Now the issue is with the caching. Because every time the same link is referred thus, browser shows the data from the previous request and don't actually read the updated file.
The reason I know it is caching issue is because, when I open it on fresh browser I see the updated content. After I run it second time with different request, again it shows me the same data

I have already tried

```
$http.get(url, {cache: false}
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

on my aspx page_load function.

How can I make it to read the updated file? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 Response.Cache.SetNoStore();`

> Put this code in page load. Now there will be no data in cache browser will try to get the page from the server

Comment: No, it is not working. I tried both on chrome and IE. Let me add 1 more thing. as angular page in a iframe which is at the second view of the asp multiview content. I added the above code on the button that activate that view but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not found any solution to my problem thus I have changed the logic.

Following is what I am doing now which is perfectly working:

1 Asp. net website

2 Angular app embedded via IFrame

3 First user clicks on the .net button that saves a response in a .csv file on the server. On every   click different data is updated on the file. So, I am adding a function that adds the time stamp to name of file on each click

4 Sending the file to the client script via query string hash value . Adding the name of the file as hash value

5 At client side using $scope.$watch, watching the url and on each url change, gets the file name and loads the data from the location.

Now I am facing one more problem which is over here:
[Add hash to the current url without reload in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799441/)

If, anyone can help me with that?

Thanks