# Add hash to the current url without reload in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am trying to update the current url by appending # value. My problem is when I run the following commands then it refreshes the page

```
      this.Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl+ "#" + hashvalue);
      this.Response.Redirect("/my path#"+hashvalue);
```

It refreshes my page. I don't want it to refresh as I have to preserve some view on the page. I know such options are available in javascript and jquery but how can I do that in C# asp.net

I have checked other answers on this forum but could not found any for c#

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using C# because ASP.NET is server-side technology. You could use jquery to post AJAX request(s) to your ASP.NET application and then refresh certain parts of your page. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/